# Cannot flash a working custom recovery on a rooted LG G2 D802(T)

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, clockworkmod-recovery, lg-g2

I own an LG G2 D802**T**. I have rooted it successfully with **IORoot**, but when I try to flash a custom recovery on it, it always fails.

I have also tried **AutoRec** for **D802T**. Although it flashes and I am able to enter into TWRP, the phone got stuck at LG Logo and the only option left is to flash a kdz through LG Flash Tool again. I have searched for it on several forums but was unable to find the answer. Also, I have tried several apps from Play Store as well.

How can I flash **TWRP** or **CWM** which work 100%?

Comment: rooting alone might not be sufficient. Is the bootloader unlocked? I have an LG O4X, and there you only can install a custom recovery after unlocking the bootloader. I'd wonder if that would be different for the G2.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is that before you install recovery, copy the zip file for any ROM (I did CloudyG2 3.3). Then once you boot into recovery, wipe the cache and Dalvik cache, and then install the zip. Once the installation is successful, the phone will boot into the ROM without getting stuck at the LG logo. Once you are into the ROM, you can switch off the phone and try to use the key combination (vol down + power keys) to go into recovery. Or else download an app that lets you boot into recovery.

For more info, go to [XDA Forums - [Complete Guide] Convert D802T to D802 with TWRP+CloudyG2+Dorimanx_Kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g2/general/complete-guide-convert-d802t-d802-t3184830). Look for my comment on page 2 for more details.